# Expand all comments script

Tags: script, comments

The following script for Tampermonkey (multi browser) or Greasemonkey (Firefox) automatically expands all comments which are normally hidden behind the "show ... more comments" link:

[image: pic of "show more comments" link]

The code is based on the [fantastic, but unfortunately deleted, answer from Brock Adams](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119439/192282) ([screenshot for users below 10k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhALK.png)) - Thank you!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange, Expand All Comments
// @author      Taken from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119439/192282
// @description Automatically shows all comments for questions and answers
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @exclude     *://api.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://blog.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude     *://data.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://elections.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://openid.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude     *://*/review
// @grant       none
// @version     1.1
// @history     1.1 Avoid clicking on disabled "add a comment" links.
// @history     1.0 Initial release.
// ==/UserScript==
try {
    //--- This is a utility function that SE currently provides on its pages.
    StackExchange.ready (function () {
        $('.js-show-link').not (".dno").trigger ('click');
    } );
}
catch (e) {
    console.error (
      "***Userscript error: StackExchange.ready() is no longer defined!"
    , e);
}
```

---

Known issues:

- May not expand comments if cookies are disabled (side effect of SE's anonymous user handling).

Comment: Just a few days ago, I decided to write a script to do this, today I find you've prepared one for me. Thank you. It works perfectly. +1

Comment: @3D1T0R You'll have to thank @ BrockAdams -- it's all his magic doing!

Comment: @BrockAdams & @​samcarter: Thanks. Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner, but it really is working perfect for me now. I do have to wonder though about the coding style. I find it very weird to have spaces between function-name and parenthesis. Is there a particular reason for this?

Comment: Also: You can use `// @exclude     *://blog.*` & `// @exclude     *://chat.*`.

Comment: This script, may it be beautifully short and concise as it is, has one issue: compared to [StackExchange – Expand Hidden Comments](https://stackapps.com/q/8514/29193) it doesn't scroll to the (textual) point on the page were you initially were after expansion. And, BTW, the link to Brock Adam's answer that you mention is dead now.

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica Scrolling to the textual point on the page does indeed not work, but the colour highlighting of the comment/answer still works, so I usually just pay attention to the colour highlighting and then scroll myself. I added screenshot of Brock Adam's answer for the below 10k users, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: At the moment it also doesn't work for just-added comments (the site can automatically load posted comments with JavaScript)